# QGIS: Zoom to selected feature via plugin doesn't works in first attempt

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I recently migrated from QGIS 2.18 to QGIS 3.6. In the plugin, I load a vector layer and then select and zoom to a particular feature.
This worked fine in v2.18 but now on 3.6, what happens is the layer is loaded, feature is selected but zoom to that feature doesn't work in first attempt.

But when I open my plugin again in the same session (without closing the previous instance), it works fine.

Code used to zoom to feaure:

```
def zoom_to_tile(self):
    print("zoom_to_tile")
    print('zooming to tile:', self.current_tile)
    box = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(str(self.current_tile[2])).boundingBox()
    box.grow(.002)
    # self.iface.mapCanvas().setExtent(box)
    # self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
    # self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    print("selected ",self.mortonTileVLayer.selectedFeatures()[0][0],
          " iface:",self.iface.activeLayer().selectedFeatures()[0][0])
    canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()

    canvas.zoomToSelected(self.mortonTileVLayer)

    canvas.refresh();
    print("zoomed")
```

I need help to get it working first time around.

Comment: Does the function run in the first attempt (e.g. do the print statements appear)?

Comment: Yes..it does...This is what bugs me..

Comment: Can you [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/314504/edit) your question to include the `mortonTileVLayer()` function? Perhaps there may be an issue there?

Comment: It is a variable of type QgsVectorLayer and holds reference to current vector layer

Comment: I've also tried the code that is commented in the above code block like setting the extent of mapCanvas() but to no avail..

Comment: I'm in a bit of fix here.. Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Would it be possible to zip your plugin and upload it publicly so that others could test it?