# QGIS3 ZoomToSelected() not working in QGIS Editor Script but works in Python Console

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Using 3.10.1-A Coruña on Windows 10

I am writing a Python Script in the QGIS Editor but `iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()` does not appear to be working at all in the Editor.

`iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()` - works fine in the Python Console

**Editor code - apparently does nothing**

```
selectid = [2]
poalayer.select(selectid)
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected() # does nothing
iface.mapCanvas().refresh();
```

**Console - works as expected**

```
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

Let me know if I can provide any further info or do a test.

**Added additional info:** There's something obviously wrong here. From this reply ([QGIS: Zoom to selected feature via plugin doesn't works in first attempt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/314504/qgis-zoom-to-selected-feature-via-plugin-doesnt-works-in-first-attempt)) I tried running my script a second time in the same session and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried in the console, in the editor and in a plugin and everything works very well.

**The code in the console:**

```
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

**The code in the editor:**

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selectid = [2]
layer.select(selectid)
iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

**The code in the plugin:**

```
# At the beginning 
import qgis.utils
from qgis.utils import iface

# In run() function. I added a pushbutton.
self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.zoom_canvas)
self.dlg.show()

# The function when I press on the push button (after run() function)
def zoom_canvas(self):
    iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected()
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent Bré. I don't fully understand why your version works and mine did not. I did shut down the computer overnight so maybe I needed to reboot QGIS. I'll try rebooting QGIS if I have these sorts of problems in the future.